# On refresh remove hashbang from URL in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When navigating a site that's using angularjs when changing routes it adds a hashbang at the end and can resume the state on refresh (which is very cool).

However in my particular project I would like it on refresh to load the main route (like it would if there would be no hashbang).

Is this possible?

Comment: my understanding is that you want to make the browser on refresh to navigate to a different URL. and you want to accomplish this from javascript. I do not see how this is possible from javascript. In addition, this won't be a refresh anymore, but something else, which may upset the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using either a service or multiple controllers.  Easiest way IMO is to set up a simple controller and service that is included on every page.

Something like this:

```
<div style='display:none;' ng-controller='RefreshController'></div>
```

Service:

```
.factory('redirect',function($rootScope){
    var rScope={};
    rScope.redirect=true;
    rScope.set=function(){
        rScope.redirect=false;
    };
    rScope.get=function(){
        return rScope.redirect;
    };
    return rScope;
});
```

Controller:

```
function RefreshController($location,redirect){
    if($location.path()=='/'){
        redirect.set()
    }
    if(redirect.get()){
        $location.path('/');
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, if you are on the main page, it will set a service variable to say that you are on the home page.  As long as no refresh is done, the service variable state will be static.  If a refresh is done and you are not currently on the main page, the service variable will be different, and the user will be redirected to the main page.